# RAID1 in Linux makes HDD light always on?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, raid, raid-1

I made a RAID1 using two SATA HDD in Ubuntu 19.04 following [this guide](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Ffortinux.gitbooks.io%2Fhumble_tips%2Fcontent%2Fadministrar_gnulinux%2Ftutorial_configurando_un_sistema_raid_en_gnulinux.html).

It seems to work properly, but once mounted the HDD lights are always on.

**Is it normal?**

I only using one half of each disk. I plan to using the remaining part for make a RAID0 (now they have a clean partition). I test the performance of the RAID1 using Disk and I get reasonable results when comparing with each disk individually.  I the writing speed is similar to the slower disk, and the reading speed is almost twice of the slower disk.

I tested before the speed of one of the disks using Disks. It's speed was 100MB/s, 85MB/s and 11ms (for reading, writing and access time). The same disk now gives in the clean partition (the unused half) 73MB/s, 40MB/s and 52ms. I do not know the reason. *Can it be due to now it is clean and before I tested an ext4 partition?* Or *is it normal when part of the disk is used for a RAID array?* Or *may it be due the same reason that makes the HDD light always on?*

It is my first RAID and I want make it work properly before storing important data.

Thank you.

Comment: "It is my first RAID and I want make it work properly before storing important data." -- make sure you have backups, RAID is not a backup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HDD light should only go on when the RAID is being read/written to.  If its a newly configured RAID, yes, this is normal as the drive syncs/copies itself (even if it has no data on itself). This can take a long time - hours or days depending on size/spec of disks - To check if this is the case/how far through the process of building it is, from a terminal window type "cat /proc/mdstat".  It is fairly safe (but slower) to copy data to the drive during this process as any data written will be mirrored immediately.

If the RAID is fully built and disk is supposed to be idle, then this is not right.